# Display only endpoints available to user in Swagger after his login

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I would like to setup the follownig workflow:

1. Initially, without login, Swagger shows only 2-3 endpoints - this will be done by providing limited openapi3 json from backend, no problem;
2. User logs in via Authorize button (works, openapi3 json has necessary info);
3. After login, Swagger emits one more request with user credentials, backend provides new openapi3 json with endpoints available to this specific user and Swagger redraws the page with new data. Preferably, user is still logged in.

Is it possible to do Item 3 with Swagger? How can I manually emit request from Swagger with OAuth2 bearer token (since user logged, token must present somwhere) and redraw Swagger page?

Answer (score 1):

The task was done via Swagger customization using its [plugin system](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/customization/overview/).
Actually Swagger is a JavaScript (Babel, Webpack) project using React / Redux and it was a little bit hard to dig into it since I do not know React (my tool is Python) but finally I managed.
Here is the code for my custom plugin with comments:

```js
    const AuthorizedPlugin = function(system) {
      return {
        statePlugins: {
          auth: {  // namespace for authentication subsystem
            // last components invoked after authorization or logout are
            // so-called reducers, exactly they are responsible for page redraw
            reducers: {
              "authorize_oauth2": function(state, action) {
                let { auth, token } = action.payload
                let parsedAuth

                auth.token = Object.assign({}, token)
                parsedAuth = system.Im.fromJS(auth)

                var req = {
                  credentials: 'same-origin',
                  headers: {
                    accept: "application/json",
                    Authorization: "Bearer " + auth.token.access_token
                  },
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: system.specSelectors.url()
                }
                // this is the additional request with token I mentioned in the question
                system.fn.fetch(req).then(
                  function (result) {
                    // ... and we just call updateSpec with new openapi json
                    system.specActions.updateSpec(result.text)
                  }
                )

                // This line is from the original Swagger-ui code
                return state.setIn( [ "authorized", parsedAuth.get("name") ], parsedAuth )
              },
              "logout": function(state, action) {
                var req = {
                  credentials: 'same-origin',
                  headers: { accept: "application/json" },
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: system.specSelectors.url()
                }
                // for logout, request does not contain authorization token
                system.fn.fetch(req).then(
                  function (result) {
                    system.specActions.updateSpec(result.text)
                  }
                )
                // these lines are to make lock symbols gray and remove credentials
                var result = state.get("authorized").withMutations(function (authorized) {
                  action.payload.forEach(function (auth) {
                    authorized.delete(auth);
                  });
                });
                return state.set("authorized", result)
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

Insert this plugin as usual:

```js
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({{
        url: '{openapi_url}',
        dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
        defaultModelsExpandDepth: -1,
        displayOperationId: false,
        presets: [
            SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
            SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          AuthorizedPlugin
        ],
        layout: "BaseLayout",
        deepLinking: true
    })
```